# Optionals and unwrapping

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

What I am trying to accomplish is this - I have two text fields and I want to `print()` a message to the console if the username text field `.isEmpty` or if the password field `.isEmpty`. The first thing I noticed is that the text fields are optional as they of course can be empty. So could anyone explain to me some of the syntax and reasoning behind the following code samples?

Q1: Why must I unwrap after the `.isEmpty`?

```
if(self.username.text?.isEmpty)! {
    print("Something!")
}
```

Q2: Why does this syntax not work when you include an or operator?

```
if(self.username.text?.isEmpty || self.password.text?.isEmpty)! {
    print("Please provide username and password!")
}
```

Q3: Why can I not unwrap directly after the `.isEmpty`?

```
if(self.username.text?.isEmpty! || self.password.text?.isEmpty!) {
    print("Please provide username and password!")
}
```

Comment: This might help: [Optional Chaining Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Q1**: 
You must unwrap, because the `text` property can be `nil`. Maybe because it is a valid value, maybe because it's an artifact of Objective-C conversion and it is really `nil_resettable`.

Using `!` is unsafe, because it can crash whenever you access the text, if it is unset.

Try something like this

```
if self.username.text?.isEmpty == false {
    print("Something!")
}
```

Swift has an implicit non optional to optional promotion if the required type is optional.

At first it was `Bool? == Bool` and it got changed to `Bool? == Bool?`

**Q2**: Why does this syntax not work when you include an or operator?

```
let a: Bool? = self.username.text?.isEmpty
let b: Bool? = self.password.text?.isEmpty
let c = a || b // the problem here is that `Bool?` doesn't implement 
               // the operator `||` as it's not clear how this would
               // work with optionals.
```

You want to do:

```
guard let username = self.username.text,
   let password = self.password.text,
   !username.isEmpty,
   !password.isEmpty {

    print("Please provide username and password!")
    return
}

// code using username as String and password as String (not optionals)
```

**Q3**:

You need to fix your parenthesizing.

```
if (self.username.text?.isEmpty)! || (self.password.text?.isEmpty)! {
    print("Please provide username and password!")
}
```

Please remember not to use `!` in production code. This is unsafe. Use the variant from **Q2**.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Why must I unwrap after the .isEmpty?

```
if(self.username.text?.isEmpty)! {
    print("Something!")
}
```

The `if` statement structure forces you to have `true/false` in the body, to simplify:

```
let condition = false

if condition {...}
```

When you unwrap this statement `self.username.text?.isEmpty` you are telling the compiler "I promise that it is never `nil`" even that it could be.

> Q2: Why does this syntax not work when you include an or operator?

The same reason as before the input for `or`/`and` operator must be not `nil` (unwrapped).

Notice the line below. If you try and evaluate this statement, you will see that you are attempting to unwrap a boolean, with two optionals as parameters.

```
if(self.username.text?.isEmpty || self.password.text?.isEmpty)! {
```

> Q3: Why can I not unwrap directly after the .isEmpty?

I am guessing here, based on the issue you presented.

`isEmpty` is not an optional, it can be true/false, therefore cannot be unwrapped.

This statement `self.username.text?.isEmpty` is optional, it can be `true/false/nil` and can be unwrapped.

I hope it helps to make things clearer. Reading about [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) and analyzing Apple's code examples might help even more.